# Parsing LocalDate to String in getter and setter methods

Tags: java, spring, date, java-time, localdate

I had a class in Java (Spring) and one of the variables was type Date (called fnac, which stores a birthdate, so I don't need hours!)

These were their set and get methods:

```
public String getFnac() {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+2"));
        return format.format(this.fnac);
    }


public void setFnac(String fnac) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+2"));
    this.fnac = format.parse(fnac);
}
```

I've decided to use LocalDate, as everyone seems to say that it's newer and better, and... 
I would like to addapt the setter and getter to LocalDate

```
@Column(name = "FNAC")
    private LocalDate fnac;
```

I've been trying and searching for hours but I couldn't addapt it to LocalDate yet..
Here are my last try:

```
    public void setFnac(String fnac) throws ParseException {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(fnac, formatter.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
    this.fnac = zdt.toLocalDate();

}



public String getFnac() {
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    ZonedDateTime zdt = now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    return zdt.format(formatter).toString();
}
```

(I may have anything right in the setter, but... I'm sorry you have to read such a disaster getter...)

PD: Yes, I have LocalDate persisted with this: https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/

With only this code it will store dates "sucessfully":

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

But seems that I need to work with time-zones because... when I save a date in the database, it will save the previous day (because it seems to save with dd/mm/yyyy at 00:00 UTC+0), so if I set a birthdate as 07/10/2015 it will save 06/10/2015. 
I don't even understand why LocalDate is even saving an hour. I'm using LocalDate for a reason, not LocalDateTime. I only want Dates, but the times keep pursuiting me!

I'm UTC+2 (but I think it doesn't makes sense to store UTC+2 because the next week we will be UTC+1), so I think it would be ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid") (I suposse then that it will change the hour automatically when the time zones changes).

I hope you can help me! (I'm sorry for my english, it's not perfect). Thank you!

Comment: can you show your sample input string  `String fnac`

Comment: And also your database might be in different time zone

Comment: Have you considered storing the date as a string in the format you want in the database. That way you don't have to worry about timezones.

Answer (score 3):

## `LocalDate.parse`

This is a lot easier than you seem to think.

```
public void setFnac(String fnac) {
    this.fnac = LocalDate.parse(fnac);
}

public String getFnac() {
    return fnac.toString();
}
```

I am exploiting the fact that your strings are in ISO 8601 format, the default format for the classes of java.time, the modern Java date and time API. So `LocalDate` parses this format without any explicit formatter, and also returns it from its `toString` method.

Just forget everything about the old `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. java.time can do it all for you. And also don’t worry about time zone because a `LocalDate` hasn’t got any. If the date is saved incorrectly to the database, there’s a bug somewhere in the software doing that or its configuration/setup that you need to pursue.

**Link:** [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: It's storing the PREVIOUS day. If I change the database field (DATE to DATATIME) it will store as the previous day, 00.00 h.
I can't understand why and I can't find the bug :S

That's why I was looking for using time zones. 
I had no problems with Date, but as everyone says to use LocalDate... I changed that :/

Comment: It’s pretty clearly a time zone issue somewhere. You can’t solve it in your Java class (or if you were to, you could add 1 day, but that would be a very awful hack that you wouldn’t want and that would be very likely to give you other problems).

Comment: It seems to work now that I've changed my spring.datasource.url=..................&serverTimezone=Europe/Madrid in the application.properties

I tried to change that value setting "UTC+2", but it didn't recognize it and I didn't know what to write, lol

Before the change, it was UTC. I can't understand why UTC would store the date as a previous day. Europe/Madrid is UTC+2 and it's 15:50 PM. Well, I have a slighty idea why, but seems too complicate.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The database you are currently using doesn't have the concept of `LocalDate` and when you convert the `LocalDate` to the normal `Date` class, it carries along the hours an minutes set to midnight `00:00` Then when the database stores the object in the database it will save the date and add the servers timezone offset to it.

Here is an example of converting a `LocalDate` to `Date`

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println("From LocalDate: " + date);

Date d = Date.from(date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

System.out.println("From Date" + d);
```

Output:

```
From LocalDate: 2019-10-23
Form Date: Wed Oct 23 00:00:00 UTC 2019
```

As you can see the timezone is still stored in the date even though there was no time stored in your LocalDate. This is essentially what your conversion is doing.

The easiest way to remediate the timezone problem would be to store the date as a string in your desired format then convert as needed. This will be consistent regardless of what timezone your server is on and where you are located.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change this line in application.properties

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/...........&serverTimezone=**UTC**

to this line:

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/...........&serverTimezone=**Europe/Madrid**

I tried before with UTC+2, but it didn't exist

Changing that config and the answer of Ole V.V. worked for me

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you don't require time then you need to use the only **LocalDate**.

```
public void setFnac(String fnac) {
    this.fnac = LocalDate.parse(fnac, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}
```

No need to use ZonedDateTime for this. Hope this wil help.

Comment: The [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58528490/642706) already covered this. And that Answer did so more succinctly as there is no need to define a formatting pattern as shown in your Answer.